# IE decodes umlauts in encoded urls to wrong charset

Tags: php, internet-explorer, encoding, character-encoding

I have a file url (file:///...) with an umlaut in a intranet solution.

The url is encoded which turned the `ä` into an `%C3%A4`.

When I click the link in Firefox/Chrome the character is an `ä` and the file is displayed.
In IE the character is changed to `Ã` which results in a 404-error.

I tried with and without the following charset definition but it does not seem to work. (The file is UTF-8 encoded)

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

I tried without encoding which does work but since I am using PHP-DOMDoc which causes the encoding I would rather not parse the content again.

I cannot avoid the umlauts in the urls since the customer enters these.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: UTF-8 in URLs is unreliable at best... especially on the `file:///` scheme.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol using ISO-8859-1 has the same effect.

Comment: In general, URLs should only include characters in the range [33-127], with some encoded appropriately. Although... try accessing the file with %E4 in place of the ä.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this works in IE but fails in FF/Chrome

Comment: Well, the only solution then is to just not use umlaut letters. Use "ae" instead.

Comment: Percent encoding does not define any particular character encoding, it simply encodes *bytes*. It it entirely up to the receiver to decode those bytes into characters. There's no specification for how this should work, so you're pretty much fundamentally screwed.